# Redirect every query to file in upper folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, directory, subdirectory

I have this structure on my WebServer:

```
\main
   index.php
```

The `index.php` file is accessible with `www.example.com/main/`.

Now I want to redirect every query with a sub folder structure (of not existing folders) to my `index.php` file and pass the entered URL.

Like:

```
www.example.com/main/world/fish
www.example.com/main/hasuisdg
www.example.com/main/bowl/soup
www.example.com/main/salat
```

All these URLs should be answered by my `index.php` while passing the URL.

General example:

Code of `index.php`:

```
<?php

echo passedurl(); //this is the function I am looking for

?>
```

Entering `www.example.com/main/ilikestackoverflow` in browser.
Showing `www.example.com/main/ilikestackoverflow` on webpage.

Not absolutely important:

The URL changes to `www.example.com/main/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Not absolutely important: The url changes to `www.example.com/main/`

You can easily do this with a front-controller pattern, except for that last bit (if that is indeed an *optional requirement* or *undesired behaviour*?). If all the URLs "changed to" `/main/` then you can't easily route the request appropriately - it would be impossible to bookmark - and it would confuse users.

You've not stated *where* you want the `.htaccess` file to go. I'll assume you want it in the root of your site. (You could alternatively have it in the `/main` subdirectory - but you would need to change the directives slightly.)

For example, using mod_rewrite to internally rewrite requests for the URL `/main/<something>` to `/main/index.php`, where `/main/<something>` does not map to a directory, try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /main

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^main/[^.]+$ index.php [L]
```

The regex `^main[^.]+$` matches URLs that do not contain a dot - so this naturally excludes requests that look-like files. So, I have excluded a check for existing files (only for existing directories - as stated).

Then, in `index.php` you can examine the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` superglobal to access the requested URL. There isn't necessarily a need to explicitly pass the requested URL to your script. Note that the PHP variable `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` also contains the query string (if any). (The `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against the URL-path only, which notably excludes the query string.)